# Eclipse hotkey that word wraps all my code?

Tags: eclipse, word-wrap, hotkeys

Alright, this is about the tenth time this has happened to me.

I bumped some hotkey in Eclipse and it "word-wrapped" ALL OF MY CODE!!!

Example (notice the plus signs all on new lines):

```
    // Split the formula into two parts: bit/byte range, and formula.
    try {
        formulaParts = formulaAndBitPositions.split(",");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        msg("PD ERROR during decode: DPN=" + DPN
                + " formulaAndBitPositions=" + formulaAndBitPositions
                + " E= " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

So every line that was longer than about 80 characters got wrapped! grrrrrrrrr!

Anybody know which horrible horrible hotkey is responsible for this?

Comment: It's dumbass features like this (and spellcheck) that I quit using Eclipse for.

Comment: You can undo that with Ctrl-Z

Comment: @Rafe, spellcheck disablement is a single checkbox in the preferences.

Comment: Here's what I do. I fix the Java code formatter so it formats the code the way I want it, then I put "format all code" as a "save action". Eclipse will now always make sure that all code is formatted as soon as I save anything and I never have to care about formatting my code.

Comment: @Rafe: and this "dumbass feature" is one of the reasons I hate working in Visual Studio. Isn't it fun to flame around about how <your-favorit-hate-object> sucks? :D

Comment: In what universe did they think that these types of things would be a good default setting? It's just the mark of poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Format Code).

Updates:
Sorry, my mistake. Its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for Format Code. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is for Organize Code. I often mix them.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can change Format Code's behavior for different projects, so that it doesn't do wrapping etc.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O is organize imports

Comment: @Vitalii: Yeah I mean Ctrl + Shift F. I mistakenly wrote Ctrl + Shift + O. Thanks buddy. :-)

Comment: Thanks everybody! This one was bugging the heck out of me and now I know what NOT to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's Ctrl+Shift+F, but you can always change the configurations to guide how Eclipse does the formatting for you. Search "margin" or something like that in the Preferences window and change the "80" to one you like, e.g. 120.